# Problem with mathematical post and request in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests, wxpython

*So i'm having a problem completing this challenge.
The goal is to give a solution to equation in 5 seconds.
http://218.100.84.106:5006/

My script for this problem is

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import http.client
import re

a = urllib.request.urlopen('http://218.100.84.106:5006').read()
b = int(a.decode('utf8')[1106:1111])
c=int(a.decode('utf8')[1112:1117])
d=int(a.decode('utf8')[1124:1129])
e=int(a.decode('utf8')[1131:1136])
f=int(a.decode('utf8')[1143:1148])
g=int(a.decode('utf8')[1150:1155])

mod=1000000007

x=((pow(b,c))%mod*(pow(d,e))%mod*(pow(f,g))%mod)%mod

url = 'http://218.100.84.106:5006'

r = requests.post(url, data={'x':int(x)})

flag = re.search(r'HZ\{\S+\}', r.text)
flag = str(flag)

def answer():
  if flag == "":
    print(flag)
answer

print("FLAG IS: " + flag )
```

**THE ANSWER/FLAG STARTS WITH HZ{ ,and ends with }**

When i run my code it just returns:
  - FLAG IS: None

Comment: Please don't shout. And [edit] your post, checking the preview feature to make sure it looks the way you want it to. Hint: you don't need block quotes. You need code formatting.

Comment: Amongst other issues with your question, you forgot to mention what, specifically, your problem is.

Comment: What is not working in your code?

Comment: thanks for all the advice i had just began using this site and my English isn't a sunshine you know :'D

Comment: I suggest that you print out the contents of  `r.text` to find out why your search is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrite your code because you have some mistakes

1. You need a cookies , otherwise website can not know what your Calculation formula
2. you post content is wrong
3. you can get the number by regex

The code

```
import requests
import re

mod=1000000007
url = 'http://218.100.84.106:5006/index.php'

with requests.Session() as s:
    req = s.get(url)
    a = req.text
    func = re.search(r"(?<=`\().*(?=mod`)",a).group(0)
    ma = [int(e) for e in re.findall(r"\d+",func)]
    print(ma)

    x=((pow(ma[0],ma[1]))%mod*(pow(ma[2],ma[3]))%mod*(pow(ma[4],ma[5]))%mod)%mod

    print(x)

    r = requests.post(url, data={"answer":int(x),"sum":"Илгээх"},cookies=req.cookies)

    flag = re.search(r'HZ\{\S+\}', r.text).group(0)
    flag = str(flag) if flag else ""

    print("FLAG IS: " + flag )
```